# Why is my zoom wrong in this d3 code?

Tags: d3.js, css-transforms, scaletransform, translate3d

This code is running live here: http://domtree.breckyunits.com

The part that is a little off is the zoom behavior. When I zoom in on a point, it zooms correctly but translates to the wrong point. I feel like I need to do some type of transform/translate at the same time, but I'm not quite sure how to understand this stuff. I have very little practice with linear algebra and vectors/matrices.

The part of the code that needs work is the redraw function:

```
var redraw = function () {
  vis.attr("transform", "scale(" + d3.event.scale + "," + d3.event.scale + ") "
    + "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + d3.event.translate[1] + ")");
}
```

You can see all the code at https://github.com/breck7/domtree/blob/master/domtree.js

vis is defined earlier in the code:

```
vis = d3.select("#body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h )
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

do not include .call() in your [Object] "vis" for simplifie debug

read this other post :
[d3.js zoom xScale / xAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433951/d3-js-zoom-xscale-xaxis/14927154#14927154)

```
var vis, zm; // as global !
vis.call(zm=d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", draw));
function draw() {
    console.log(zm.scale(), zm.translate());
}
```